# Creating a batch-file to remove "tel:" from the front of a number

Tags: batch-file, dos

I am trying to create a batch file that removes "tel:" from a number and then passes it to a softphone to call. For example, tel:1234567890 would pass through as 1234567890. I was advised to use the following:

```
@echo off
set "URI=%~1"
set "URI=%URI:tel:=%"
somecommand %URI%
```

I implemented it like this:

```
@echo off 
set "URI=%~1"
set "URI=%URI:tel:=%"
"E:\Program Files\qutecom\qutecom.exe" -c call/%1 %URI%
```

The softphone dials the number, but the "tel:" is still there. Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to remove the %1 from the last line.

"E:\Program Files\qutecom\qutecom.exe" -c call/%URI%

Comment: That worked perfectly. I guess it is unnecessary, because it is already being passed from the registry. I wish I could give you an upvote.